# PHP mysqli_real_escape_string() not working inside function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a function that adds a log entry to my database as follows:

```
function doLog($conn, $category, $result, $details){
    $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $category);
    $result = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $result);
    $details = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $details);

    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO log (category, result, details) VALUES('$category', '$result', '$details')");
    return $details; //for debug
}

echo doLog2($conn, "Test", "Test", "A 'test' entry"); //echo is for debug
```

**A 'test' entry** is returned/echoed as **A \'test\' entry**, but is inserted into my database without the slashes.

How can this be?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY). That should actually fix your problem.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: Funny, I was just reading about prepared statements minutes before you said this.. Thanks though. This doesn't have any sort of interaction right here, so no vulnerabilities, but I'll definitely look into it for the other parts of the site that the user can interact with the db.

Comment: If you read the [documentation for `mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php), it'd tell you just that. And like its been pointed out, prepared statements replace this function.

Answer (score 2):

This is working correctly. The backslashes are to escape the quotes in the SQL query, so that the quote characters are inserted verbatim. It's not supposed to *also* insert the escape character `\`.

If you had applied escaping twice, you'd end up with an escaped backslash followed by an escaped quote like this:

```
A \\\'test\\\' entry
```

What would be stored in the database would be:

```
A \'test\' entry
```

All this is much simpler if you use parameterized statements. You don't do any quoting or escaping.

```
function doLog($conn, $category, $result, $details){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO log (category, result, details) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $category, $result, $details);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    return $details; //for debug
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. maybe I'm doing something differently? I've always used about the same code in the past and it's always escaped the character in the database. But regardless, if it echoes as \' shouldn't it be \' in the database too?

Comment: @ShaneT The way it's escaped in the query an the way it's stored in the database are two different things. This is just the same as how `&` in HTML is `&amp;` in the source, or in a regular string how `\"` shows up when there's double quotes in the string itself.